# Compile ascx files into DLL at runtime

Tags: asp.net, .net, ascx, aspnet-compiler, csharpcodeprovider

In our ASP.NET application we allow other developers to write asp.net code and we compile their code into in-memory dll.

As part of this we would like to be able to compile ASCX controls into DLL at **runtime** and then later on load them into Aspx Pages.

I already know how to load the Ascx control from a path (which does not work in my case, most likely the ascx file content will be in DB) and as long as I have the Control object i can add it to the Page control hierarchy.

So the key for me is how to compile the ascx files produced at **runtime** into a DLL (in-momery) so then when they are requested I would be able to add them to the Aspx pages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start from [ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb559279.aspx). And [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14147/ParseControl-during-runtime-with-a-custom-control) you will find the example project on codeproject.com.

Comment: The problem with ParseControl is that you cannot have any code in aspx control such as <script runat="server"> or most likely <%=Your Code %>

Comment: What do you mean "C'mon!" do you have a better suggestion?